# Does a 2D (real-space) wavefunction always has to be a product of two 1D wavefunction (i.e. always separable)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

In the first-quantization formalism for many particle quantum mechanics, let $|x \rangle$ and $|y \rangle$ be two basis for two particles $A$ and $B$: $\psi_A(x) = \langle x | \psi_A \rangle$ and $\psi_B(y) = \langle y | \psi_B \rangle$.

As I understand, $| \vec{r} \rangle = |x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle$, where $\vec{r}$ is the usual 2D position vector. The many-particle state is $|\Psi \rangle = |\psi_A \rangle \otimes |\psi_B \rangle$ and the wave-function then:

$$
\Psi(\vec{r}) = \langle \vec{r} | \Psi \rangle 
= (\langle x|\otimes \langle y|)(|\psi_A \rangle \otimes |\psi_B \rangle)= \psi_A(x)\psi_B(y)
$$
So, it implies such two-particle wavefunction in 2D will always have the product form. Is that generally true or follows from the fact the particles were restricted along one-dimension to begin with?

If so, if we have a single particle moving in two dimensions, in linear-algebra language, what kind of object $(\langle x | \otimes \langle y|) |\psi\rangle $ is (in other words, if we consider the 2D position vector as a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces $x$ and $y$, which space the single-particle wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$ belong to)?

Comment: I don't understand whether you're considering the wavefunction for two particles in one dimension (for a 2D configuration space), for one particle in two dimensions (a different 2D configuration space), or for two particles in two dimensions (a 4D configuration space).

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not generally true.  The reason is that you are assuming that a general two-particle state is given by $|\psi_A \rangle\otimes |\psi_B\rangle$, and this is not the case.  A general two-particle state is a **linear combination** of product states, i.e.

$$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n |\psi_{A_n}\rangle \otimes |\psi_{B_n}\rangle $$
In the position basis, we would write

$$|\Psi\rangle = \int \mathrm dx_1 \int \mathrm dx_2  \  \psi(x_1,x_2) |x_1\rangle \otimes |x_2\rangle $$

where $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ is an element of $L^2(\mathbb R)\otimes L^2(\mathbb R)\simeq L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ and is under no obligation to factor.  If it **does** factor, so $\psi(x_1,x_2) = \psi_A(x_1) \psi_B(x_2)$, then we can write

$$|\psi\rangle  = \left(\int \mathrm dx_1 \psi_A (x_1) |x_1\rangle \right)\otimes \left(\int \mathrm dx_2 \psi_B(x_2) |x_2\rangle \right) = |\psi_A\rangle\otimes |\psi_B\rangle$$

but there is no reason to expect this to be true *a priori*.  In fact, if the two particles are indistinguishable fermions then $\psi(x_1,x_2) = -\psi(x_2,x_1)$, which is sufficient to show that they **cannot** be in a product state.

---

You may be interested in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/609231/156895) I wrote about the difference between the direct product $\mathcal H_A \times \mathcal H_B$ and the tensor product $\mathcal H_A \otimes \mathcal H_B$.  The key difference is the central point of *this* answer, namely that elements of the former are all product states while elements of the latter are *linear combinations* of product states.  Modeling composite systems using the latter construction opens up the possibility of having non-product states, which are usually called *entangled* in a physics context.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Any thought about the second part? Namely, how to interpret $|\psi \rangle$ in the second equation if it represents a single particle moving in 2-dimensions ($x_1$ and $x_2$ in the equation)? Which Hilbert space does it belong to?

Comment: @UChat I was under the impression you were asking about two particles, each of which moves in 1D. Did you mean that each particle moves in 2D?

Comment: Nope, that was the first part. As a separate but related question, if we consider a single particle moving in 2D; $\psi (x,y) = \langle x,y|\psi\rangle = (\langle x| \otimes \langle y|)|\psi\rangle$. Does the "single-particle" state vector $|\psi \rangle$for this case belong to the tensor product space spanned by $|x \rangle \otimes |y \rangle$?

Comment: @UChat The single-particle wavefunction $\psi(x,y)$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$, yes.  The Hilbert space underlying a single particle moving in two dimensions is isomorphic to the Hilbert space underlying two distingishable particles moving in one dimension.  If the particles are indistinguishable, though, this is no longer true.